# How to Properly Add Cookies to a Session in Selenium? (using Node JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have logged into to Google and stored the cookies of the session in a JSON file.

I'm trying to create a Selenium session and restore from these cookies so I can be logged in to Google on this new session.

When using Puppeteer, I am successfully able to restore my session, this code works to restore my session:

```
const page = await driver.newPage()

try {
    await page.goto("https://google.com")
    //driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeOut(30, 
TimeUnit.SECONDS)
}
catch (err) {
    return console.log("ERROR WITH PROXY: " + err.message)
}

await page.setCookie(...cookies)

await page.reload()
await page.goto("https://google.com")
```

However, when I try to do the same in Selenium, I get no errors but my session isn't restored after adding the cookies and reloading the page. Code is the following:

```
var data = fs.readFileSync("Accounts.json")
var json = JSON.parse(data)
var options = new chrome.Options()
var cookiesProxies = GetAccount(json, account)

var arguments = SetOptions(cookiesProxies.proxy)
var cookies = cookiesProxies.cookies
options.addArguments(arguments)
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
.withCapabilities(options)
.forBrowser("chrome")
.build()

await driver.get("https://google.com")

await driver.manage().addCookie(...cookies)

await driver.navigate().refresh()
```

I even tried to pass all individual cookie dictionaries to the function and it still didn't work.

Any ideas?